# laravel 5 - getting redirected to website's root when having some values in form

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5

here's my blade file : `example.com/add`

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">
    <label><span>title</span>
        <input type="text" name="title" value="{{old('title')}}">
    </label>
    <label><span>address</span>
        <input type="text" name="address" value="{{old('address')}}">
    </label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="add">
</form>
```

and here's my `routes.php` file:

```
Route::get('/',function(){
    return 'welcome home!';
});
Route::get('add','AdminController@add');//just view's the blade file
Route::post('add',function(){
    dd(Request::all());
});
```

so after the form get's submitted to itself by `post` method, I should see all the data passed through form and I do for most of the times...
but sometimes It doesn't work and instead It redirect's me to `example.com` and I see the **welcome home** message which must be seen through get method !
I found that It's not some random thing happening accidentally , for example It'll always happen when I fill one of fields with this value : `accept-charset="UTF-8"`
this problem only exist on the **shared host** and I don't have the same on localhost.
thanks

---

**UPDATE:** I tried filling the action attribute with the address , didn't help

Comment: `<form action="" method="post">`. here why your form action is blank with no routes?

Comment: it doesn't differ with the exact address of current page

Comment: check your `.htaccess` as well

Answer (score 0):

I think your code need to update like:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/add')) }}
   <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">
   <label><span>title</span>
       <input type="text" name="title" value="{{old('title')}}">
   </label>
   <label><span>address</span>
       <input type="text" name="address" value="{{old('address')}}">
   </label>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="add">
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Hope this work for you!

Comment: I still have the same problem, look's like It's all about having some special characters in the post request